# Uncertainty Theorem

Tags: physical-chemistry, quantum-chemistry

What is the physical meaning of Heisenberg's Uncertainty Principle? We have derived it mathematically but what is the logical explanation for it?

Comment: So...you're saying there isn't any logic in the math? 8D

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/59822/derivation-of-the-heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

Comment: @paracetamol I meant to say is there any logical deduction of the principle(not formula) without involving complex mayhematics.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave%E2%80%93particle_duality#Brief_history_of_wave_and_particle_viewpoints

Comment: Possible duplicate - [Heisenbergs uncertainty principle](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/14848/16683). (Digressing, but what a crappy title - bonus points to anybody who edits that question.)

Comment: [need explanation of principle without mathematics](https://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/quantum.png)

Comment: The physical meaning is that your cannot measure the exact position and exact momentum *at the same  time*. The principle gives a limit on both quantities if we try and measure both simultaneously. You can accurately measure position and momentum if done separately .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [wave packet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_packet) is localized in space, but it is a superposition of many waves of different wavelengths.

A simple wave has a distinct wavelength, but it is spread out in space.

The wavelength corresponds to the momentum of a particle: $p = \frac{h}{\lambda}$.

These are examples where you can't know both the position and wavelength (i.e., momentum) of a wave form.